# Looping through an array of simple html dom links and inserting into mySQL table based on unique id

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, simple-html-dom

I have an multidimensional array named `$trans` that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => Vol 19, No 2 (2018)
            [2] => Africa Sanguine
            [3] => https://www.ajol.info/index.php/asan/issue/view/17048
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => Vol 19, No 1 (2017)
            [2] => Africa Sanguine
            [3] => https://www.ajol.info/index.php/asan/issue/view/16693
        )

)
```

I have been trying to extract metadata based on the url in each array and match it with the unique id of each array in this case id 1 for array 0 and id 2 for array 1 respectively. I have been successful in extracting the metadata but when it comes to inserting this to a mysql table i get into problems where all records are allocated the id of the last inserted array. e.g., all records are allocated id 1. How can i resolve this?

The code i am using to get the metadata looks like this

```
//create a multidemnsional array called $trans
    array_unshift($citation, null);
        $trans = call_user_func_array('array_map', $citation);
        print_r($trans);

        //loop through trans and get metadata for url found in $value3  
        foreach($trans as $key => $value){
        //echo $value[3].'<br>';
        $html2 = file_get_html($value[3]);
        foreach($html2->find('table[class="tocArticle"]') as $div2) {
        $DOM = new DOMDocument();
        $DOM->loadHTML($div2);
        $Detail = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('td');
        $i = 0;
        $j = 0;
        foreach($Detail as $sNodeDetail) {
            $aDataTableDetailHTML[$j][] = trim($sNodeDetail->textContent);
            $j = $i % count($aDataTableDetailHTML[$j]) == 0 ? $j + 1 : $j;
        }
        }
        }
     print_r($aDataTableDetailHTML);
```

Comment: Including the code with the problem would help in solving this issue.

Comment: @Nigel i have just edited question to include code

Comment: If it's always item [0] that is the value you are looking for then just use `var_dump(array_column($Detail, 0));`

Comment: The var_dump returns NULL. I am actually looking for item[0],item[1] and item[3]